# Dojo FilteringSelect or MultiSelect not working on IPad(IOS 8)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm a developing a web application by using dojo(v1.7).There is a drop down list & I coded it as below;

```
<div class="forminput noshadow ">
                <select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" value="" 
                name="itemSelection" id="itemSelection" 
                class="select1 " placeHolder="Select Item" required="false">
</select>
</div>
```

Data is populated by selection tool as below;(data1=item list)

```
itemCategoryStore = new dojo.store.Memory({
                        data : data1
    });
dijit.byId("itemSelection").store=itemCategoryStore;
```

But this can be executed properly in windows environment,but it is not working in Ipad(IOS 8),

What could be the root cause for this? Any suggestions to solve this issue?